# Adding clickable image placeholders to page layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout, image

I'm building a public-facing website (publishing site) using Sharepoint 2013.

I have a page layout - used for the website's front page - which will mainly be used to display banners that lead to other parts of the website. So what I need is a snippet to add to the page layout that simply allows the person editing the page to specify an image from the publishing Image library to display in that place holder. There will be a few of those place holders, each displaying a separate image and they need to be clickable, taking the user to a page in the Page library.

The closest thing I've found is the Image viewer web part but it doesn't allow an admin to change the image in edit mode. I also don't think it supports making the image clickable.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is divide the Page Layout using WebPartZones. We then add Content Editor Webparts on to the Page, there we can link the image using "a" tag, Here the admin can go to the edit mode and adjust the images and links in Edit Mode also

Answer (score 0):

What you can use are Promoted Links.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUJ5oRKwTyU

It's possible to allow users to edit/add the 'icon' but it might be a bit cumbersome. Try it out, maybe it'll help you.

M